# Create a hexagon pattern

Tags: modifiers

How can i make a pattern like this to be repeated an undefined number of times? I've tried to use the array modifier and so far I couldn't figure it out.
[image: pattern]

Answer (score 8):

Your question is not clear enough, but if you're talking about a 3D object, here is a way to do it (maybe there's a simpler?):

- Create a 6 vertices circle, subdivide it once, extrude it inwards and merge.
- Extrude it up on the Z axis.
- Extrude a 12 vertices cylinder from one of its face.

[image]

- Delete 5/6 of the shape so that you only keep 1/6.
- Put an empty at the same point as the origin of the object.
- Use it as the object of an *Array* modifier / *Object Offset* mode, *Count* = 6.
- Rotate the empty 60° on the Z axis so that the shape make a 360° star shape.

[image]

- Apply the *Array* modifier. Delete the empty.
- Repeat the star shape 7 times, use the *Snap* option / *Vertex* mode to make the shapes stick to each others.
- Only keep the centre of this shape, it will be your pattern.
- Remove any doubles.

[image]

- Give it an *Array* modifier / *Relative Offset* mode, on the X axis. Choose the amount of iterations with the *Count* value.
- Give it a second *Array* modifier / *Relative Offset* mode, on the Y axis.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Model a single hexagon and set array relative  X offset to 0.5. Remove objects that cause Z-fighting.